# Vertical align middle text in div not working

Tags: css, html

I have code like this:

```
<div class="more-options clearfix">
<div class="boxes">
    <img alt="#" src="images/icons/onl-marketing.png">
    <p>Online Marketing News</p>
</div>
<!-- end .boxes -->
<div class="boxes">
    <img alt="#" src="images/icons/str-success.png">
    <p>Stories Success</p>
</div>
<!-- end .boxes -->
```

I want to vertical align p tags middle in div, images float left and div.box:last-child has margin-left: 1%; I try this css but it doesn't work:

```
div.more-options {

    margin: 15px 0;

    div:first-child {
        .fleft;
    }

    div:last-child {
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
    div.boxes {
        padding: 20px;
        width: 49.5%;
        background: #ecf0f1;
        min-height: 25px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;

        img {
            .fleft;
            margin-right: 25px;
            .img-responsive;
            max-width: 25%!important;
        }
        p {
            .fontfc(26px, #666666);
        }
    }
    /* end div.boxes */
}
/* end div.more-options */
```

**How can I vertical align text and keep margin 1% div.boxes:last-child?**

Comment: Not `valign: middle;` but `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: This is live demo, please see http://baogiadientu.com/demo/home/news.php. It's on the bottom of page :)

Comment: It is not CSS. CSS does not have nested rules.

Comment: it's nested for less or SCSS

Comment: @c-smile sure, it's less css. Please check my live demo at http://baogiadientu.com/demo/home/news.php

Comment: @GreedyMan have you seen my fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/2HX6C/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you have some fixes:

- `p` and `img` with display:inline
- it's working the `vertical-align:middle;`
- making the parent `display: table`

EDIT: you are using padding and width: you will need an extra div for this, and with tables you need an extra cell for "separation", check this out:

updated link with images vertical aligned too:

## the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HX6C/3/)

## html:

```
<div class="more-options clearfix">
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="in">
        <img alt="#" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artbees/paradise-fruits/256/Banana-icon.png">
        <p>Online Marketing News</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end .boxes -->
    <div class="separation"></div>
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="in">
        <img alt="#" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/artbees/paradise-fruits/256/Banana-icon.png">
        <p>Stories Success</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end .boxes -->
```

## css:

```
div.more-options {

    margin: 15px 0;

    div:first-child {
    }

    div.separation {
        width: 1%;
            display: table-cell;
    }
        div.in{
            padding:20px;
        }
    div.boxes {
        width: 49.5%;
        background: #ecf0f1;
        min-height: 25px;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;

        img {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 25px;
            .img-responsive;
            max-width: 25%!important;
                vertical-align: middle;
        }
        p {
            .fontfc(26px, #666666);
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
    /* end div.boxes */
}
/* end div.more-options */
```

## the result screenshot:

[image: http://puu.sh/6Vr7w.png]

Comment: Doesn't work, put an image and you'll see. Mine does however ;)

Comment: @GreedyMan I saw your live demo and this is based on that structure

Comment: you are forgetting the 1% margin left that was the main problem of the question...

Comment: Yes, I ignored the second (not "the main") part of the question, I give you a vote for answering that part. However, this answer had ignored the alignment part (this is your original jsfiddle.net/2HX6C/1/ , PntScr: iliannikolov.com/misaligned.jpg ) ;)

Answer (score 1):

`p` elements are paragraphs - so they have a default property of display:block. Either use another element, for example a `span`.
Alternatively you can change the display property of the p dom element, for example to `display:inline`.

Update - the property of vertical align 'vertical-align:middle' should be applied to the images.

Also - your nesting of styles seems wrong, see a working example below.

Example (updated):
http://jsfiddle.net/YwV54/2/

Comment: I just changed but nothing happen :(

Comment: Your answer doesn't wokk. This is live demo, please see baogiadientu.com/demo/home/news.php. It's on the bottom of page :)

Comment: The question is "How can I vertical align text and keep margin 1% div.boxes:last-child?". The texts in the fiddle are displaying with middle vertical alignment, therefore - the answer DOES work. As I also stated in my answer - there are plenty of other issues with your code - nested css, misuse of dom elements etc.